# Phonegap GenericPush plugin unsupported

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins

While trying to install the GenericPush plugin from config.xml on PhoneGap its showing an error as GenericPush unsupported. I declared it like this.

```
<gap:plugin name="GenericPush"/>
```

As phonegap releases new plugins on 15/7/2013 i tried this also

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" />
```

but its not working.
Help mi out.

Comment: Got it     <gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.pushplugin" version="1.3.3" /> this works fine for pushnotifications in android

Comment: Add it as an answer and approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.pushplugin" version="1.3.3" />
```

this works fine for pushnotifications in android.

Comment: This is showing as plugin unsupported: com.adobe.plugins.pushplugin @ 1.3.3